# CoreData Error with 32 Bit iOS Device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

My app has a feature where it stores many NSManagedObjects which in this case are dataSets(stores: time, deviceName, setName, dataPoints(OrderedSet)). One view controller is a table view VC and lists all the stored dataSets. Each set has its own cell with a delete button, rename button, open button, label for date, and label for device name. My issue arises only on a 32bit device when I hit the open button.

This function is called when the open button is pressed:

```
func openGraph(graph: NSManagedObject){
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GraphArchiveSelected") as? GraphArchiveSelectedVC
    vc?.selectedGraph = graph
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

So I am instantiating the next VC that is used to display the data, and passing the selected DataSet(using the variable graph and selectedGraph). And this is when I am getting the error, when I am using this function:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NSManagedObject'
```

it also highlights this line of the function:

```
vc?.selectedGraph = graph [Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x38]
```

I am not sure why this works on 64 bit devices, could be an issue to do with < iOS 10. But it is able to access the individual dataSets as it is listing them on the first VC and correctly setting the label to the date, etc. One idea I had was that it could be to do with me storing values as Int64 within the DataSet. Such as the date which is the date stored as seconds since 1970. Since on the first VC I am able to see it loading the date correctly, It must not be an issue with this. I am really not sure what differences between devices could be causing this.

[Here is how the DataSets look loaded in the first VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCxce.png)

[Here is what the DataSet Entity looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H1cl.png)

[Here is what the DataPoint Entity looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiS7F.png)

Comment: I doubt that the error is only related to 32 bit devices. The Core Data error says that you are trying to create an instance of an `NSManagedObject` subclass with something else as the designated initializer. However it's required to use the designated initializer. To get more details about the exception set the exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that selectedGraph was being declared like so:

```
var selectedGraph = GraphDataSet()
```

and should have been like so

```
var selectedGraph: NSManagedObject!
```